# How to set gradient color to each div using forEach method

Tags: javascript

I have an array with gradient color values. Now I want to set each color to divs. I used the `forEach` method but only the first color is applying to all divs.

```js
var myClr = [
  "linear-gradient(to right, #4CA1AF,#C4E0E5)",
  "linear-gradient(to right, #8e2de2,#8f6ba8)",
  "linear-gradient(to right, #ee9ca7, #ffdde1)",
  "linear-gradient(to right, #0f2027, #203a43, #2c5364)",
];

const divs = document.querySelectorAll(".gradient_color");

divs.forEach((d) => {
  d.style.background = myClr;
});
```

```css
.box  {
display: flex;
flex-direction: column;
}
.gradient_color {
 height: 30px;
 width: 60px;
 margin: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
<div class="gradient_color"></div>
<div class="gradient_color"></div>
<div class="gradient_color"></div>
<div class="gradient_color"></div>
<div class="gradient_color"></div>
<div class="gradient_color"></div>
<div class="gradient_color"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: What will happen to fifth div?

Comment: i will add 50 div and 50 color values

Comment: But at any point in time, if you want to rotate the color, then you can checkout my answer

Answer (score 1):

```js
var myClr = [
  "linear-gradient(to right, #4CA1AF,#C4E0E5)",
  "linear-gradient(to right, #8e2de2,#8f6ba8)",
  "linear-gradient(to right, #ee9ca7, #ffdde1)",
  "linear-gradient(to right, #0f2027, #203a43, #2c5364)",
];

const divs = document.querySelectorAll(".gradient_color");

divs.forEach((d, i) => {
  d.style.background = myClr[i % myClr.length];
});
```

```css
.box  {
display: flex;
flex-direction: column;
}
.gradient_color {
 height: 30px;
 width: 60px;
 margin: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
<div class="gradient_color"></div>
<div class="gradient_color"></div>
<div class="gradient_color"></div>
<div class="gradient_color"></div>
<div class="gradient_color"></div>
<div class="gradient_color"></div>
<div class="gradient_color"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: hehe very simple ...Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you want to rotate the color, after 4th div if you want to add 1st color to 5th and so on then while picking the color you will have to do `myClr[index % myClr.length]`

```js
var myClr = [
  "linear-gradient(to right, #4CA1AF,#C4E0E5)",
  "linear-gradient(to right, #8e2de2,#8f6ba8)",
  "linear-gradient(to right, #ee9ca7, #ffdde1)",
  "linear-gradient(to right, #0f2027, #203a43, #2c5364)",
];

const divs = document.querySelectorAll(".gradient_color");

divs.forEach((d, index) => {
  d.style.background = myClr[index % myClr.length];
});
```

```css
.box {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.gradient_color {
  height: 30px;
  width: 60px;
  margin: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
  <div class="gradient_color"></div>
  <div class="gradient_color"></div>
  <div class="gradient_color"></div>
  <div class="gradient_color"></div>
  <div class="gradient_color"></div>
  <div class="gradient_color"></div>
  <div class="gradient_color"></div>
</div>
```